# Using SumatraPDF with XeLaTeX and TeXnicCenter

Tags: xetex, biber, texniccenter, sumatrapdf

I want to use SumatraPDF viewer for TeXnicCenter. I set it up as suggested in different manuals and it works nice when using pdflatex.
I used mainly this manual: https://pic-projekte.de/blog/sumatra-pdf-mit-texniccenter/ (it's in German, but you can get the instructions along the pictures)

But my most important file only works with XeLaTeX and Biber. If I set everything up (XeLaTeX instead of pdflatex, biber instead of bibtex), it won't work. After compiling I get the message "[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)] Cannot execute the command"

Do I have to use other settings? If yes, which ones?
I couldn't find helpful suggestions yet.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter 2.02 and SumatraPDF v3.1.2 64-bit .

EDIT: I add some (requested) screenshots:

[image: pdflatex - (La)TeX]

[image: pdflatex - Viewer]
The path is here: "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""

[image: xelatex - (La)TeX]

[image: xelatex - Viewer]
The path is here "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""

Thank you!

Comment: Please see my answer here (you are using DDE commands): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477018/16550 Which version of sumatrpadf do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The editor should never use Forward Search with -reuse-instance or -inverse search they are set-up commands not required for forward sync. Only one type of call is needed by SumatraPDF to hand back on `DOUBLE CLICK` (that's the easy bit).
[image]
The recommended reliable way to add TexnicCentre archaic command (`/ddecmd "[goto('%f', '%l')]"`) is to **add it to SumatraPDF Settings Advanced options as plain text** so check it is correctly set for your system as

```
InverseSearchCmdLine = "C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe" /ddecmd "[goto('%f', '%l')]"
EnableTeXEnhancements = true
```

The Forward Search instructs SumatraPDF where to come back to&from this is the hard part the TO could be a PDF or PS or other supported format. Commonly its the MAIN.pdf so that is %bm.pdf and if we use capital B it should work using non windows paths as well as windows ones the line number is easy that's %l (lowercase L) the hard part is choosing where you want to come back to thus is it main or subfile ? lets choose Working current.tex so adding this together it could be

```
-forward-search %Wc %l %Bm.pdf
```

So all the formats that compile pdf from TeX such as pdfLaTeX XeLaTeX should use one like this for **F5 (Jump to PDF)**

```
Kommandozeile  
Kommando:  
-forward-search "%Wc" %l "%Bm.pdf"
```

or similar :-) hence the confusion as there are dozens of placeholder combinations

[image]

One of the common issues is that TexnicCentre reports it cannot run (execute)SumatraPDF this is down to using the correct system call for the viewer. In this diagram I have simply inserted SumatraPDF.exe, in a perfectly installed system that would not be needed just send only a pdf or postscript name and SumatraPDF would open it. However recent windows makes that more difficult and in order to specify the exact line number **we need to call SumatraPDF precisely (NOTE you don't really *need* to end the line with .exe).** In a conventional windows setup SumatraPDF should have been installed to "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" so that is a good starting point.

Read all about it in the configuration guide here

https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF%20with%20TeXnicCenter.pdf

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477074/170109

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extensive explanation! I tried the configuration of @Kurt (see [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477014/inverse-search-command-sumatrapdf-in-texniccenter/477018#477018)) and it works for me. Also, I tried your answer, but I got the error that SumatraPDF.exe couldn't be executed. However, it is working right now. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Using the whole path to SumatraPDF.exe works without giving an error! :)